# Spring security OAuth authentication requires ClientId and Secret

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, oauth

In my Spring Security application I have able to use postman to fetch a JWT token from my "/oauth/token" endpoint successfully. However I wish for the /oauth/endpoint to be accessible by anybody wish to authenticate without needing clientId and secret.

My Security Server

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class GatewaySecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private GatewayUserDetailsService gatewayUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(gatewayUserDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("actuator/**").fullyAuthenticated();
    }

}
```

and my Resource Server

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
@Import(GatewaySecurityConfigurer.class)
public class GatewayResourceServerConfigurer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("actuator/**").fullyAuthenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        TokenStore store = new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
        return store;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

}
```

As you can see in both classes I've tried to implement a HttpSecurity configuration which will allow all requests to /oauth/token to be allowed which having other paths required to be authenticated. However I am struck with 401 null http responses in my postman requests when I post without clientId & secret.

How can I have my code as so clientId & Secret aren't needed to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is a authorization framework. (See RFC [6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).) It allows third-party applications (clients) to obtain limited access to an HTTP service on behalf of a user. The authorization without a client doesn't make sense.

You probably just want a simple endpoint where users can log in and get a JWT.

The following tutorial explains how to build JWT authentication with custom Spring security filters: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts